# PDF of area of convex hull of four random points in square

Tags: probability, geometry

Four points are chosen uniformly and independently from the unit rectangle $(0,1)\times(0,1)$. What is the probability distribution of the area of their [convex hull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull)?

See also [The PDF of the area of a random triangle in a square](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1974534/the-pdf-of-the-area-of-a-random-triangle-in-a-square).  An answer to this question has applications to [What is the probability of having a pentagon in 6 points](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/281229/what-is-the-probability-of-having-a-pentagon-in-6-points/1974227#1974227).

Comment: For what it's worth, the area of convex hull of four points is half of the sum of the areas of the four triangles generated by them. I don't know if it helps though.

Comment: @JiK Thanks.  That is a very astute observation.

Comment: Perhaps slightly relevant: [probability of forming a convex quadrilateral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2537421).