# Answered: With what probability do $4$ points placed uniformly randomly in the unit square of $\mathbb{R}^2$ form a convex/concave quadrilateral?

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution

I have this problem that I've struggled with for a while. If you place $4$ points randomly into a unit square (uniform distribution in both $x$ and $y$), with what probability will this shape be convex if the $4$ points are connected in some order? Equivalently, with what probability will there be a point inside the triangle with the largest area with vertices at the other $3$ points.

In particular I am interested in the answer for when this area of support is $\mathbb{R}^2$ and is uniform.

I ran a simulation and found that on a unit square the answer is about $71\%$ concave. On a unit circle picking polar co-ordinates r and theta from uniform random distributions results in a a probability of concavity of $68\%$. When the distribution for r is altered so that each point in the circle is equally likely then this falls to $51\%$.

Any advice or links for a possible answer or whether this is even possible would be appreciated.

EDIT: It turns out this problem is the same as Sylvester's 4 point problem. Alas I am 150 years too late. Thanks to all who helped. Only one person gave an answer, not quite correct but I award the bounty to them anyway for their efforts.

Comment: Also if you know how to fix my title then I'd appreciate that too.

Comment: I'm not sure that your "equivalently" is really an equivalent probability, Perhaps the right question is "what's the probability that the convex hull is a quadrilateral?" The number 71% makes me think of $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$; the last case (uniform points on a disk) giving 51% sure makes me think it's 0.5.

Comment: I thought so too. But I ran over 100,000 simulations so I know it's not 0.5. It 's slightly greater. Good point about the root 2 though.

Comment: This is pretty equivalent to "what is the expected triangle area formed by 3 uniformly random point inside a unit square". I can't think how to integrate an absolute value (`Abs[(ax - bx) (ay - cy) - (ax - cx) (ay - by)]/2`), though.

Comment: [Heron](http://mste.illinois.edu/dildine/heron/triarea.html) seems relevant here. For triangle sides of length a, b, c and semiperimeter s, area squared is s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c). Should be easier to integrate to find area in expectation.

Comment: The thing about calculating the area from 3 points is that the 4th point can either be inside that triangle, outside that triangle making a convex quadrilateral or outside that triangle forming a concave quadrilateral so it's not really about the are per se.

Comment: I have found a partial solution [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SylvestersFour-PointProblem.html). It turns out the unit circle case is called Sylvester's 4 point problem. The values in the link confirm my simulation. 

The puzzle is still open for the infinite plane problem but perhaps this helps.

Comment: @stuartstevenson So then you'll have to calculate [this area](https://i.imgur.com/xWWtTbi.png) and then integrate.

Comment: Exactly. But it's not as easy as it seems.

Comment: I'm 99% sure this has an answer somewhere

Comment: have you read this ? http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SylvestersFour-PointProblem.html

Comment: Yes, as you can see, a few points up when I posted the same link :p

Comment: "In particular I am interested in the answer for when this area of support is $\mathbb{R}^2$ and is uniform" - What do you mean? There is no uniform distribution on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Perhaps as a limiting case. Something like a normal distribution and then make the tails heavier and heavier as a limit? The difficulty is in defining such things.

Comment: @stuartstevenson You can choose any probability distribution on $\mathbb{R}^2$, for example $x$ and $y$ are independently normally distributed. Or the angle with the $x$-axis is uniformly distributed and the distance to the origin has the half-normal distribution (or any other distribution on $\mathbb{R}^+$). There is no obvious choice. It depends on the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Well what I want is so that every point is as likely as ever other. I know that defining the uniform probability density over the infinite plane sounds impossible but if you think about it, the chances that a point lands in 1 particular spot for the uniform distribution over a finite space is zero, and yet it manages to land somewhere. If anyone can give me some exact solution to the unit square or circle then I'll accept that but the infinite plane would be ideal.

Comment: The problem with the uniform density on the plane is not that it sounds impossible, but that it provably is impossible, see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/87443/uniform-distribution-on-mathbb-z-or-mathbb-r).

Comment: I fail to see how your problem is different than Sylvester's Four Point Problem for the unit square, which is already solved on the Mathworld page.

Comment: @orlp It is the same problem, but the Mathworld page doesn't give a proof. Maybe there is a proof somewhere online, but I didn't find it after a quick search.

Comment: I see now. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Paul and stuart. I believe that the concern raised by [this picture](https://i.imgur.com/xWWtTbi.png) does not apply to Sylvester's 4 point problem. After all, a convex quadrilateral $\iff$ the convex hull contains 4 points.

Comment: Perhaps [Efron 1965](https://statistics.stanford.edu/sites/default/files/SOL%20ONR%20103.pdf) is of help. Pages 5 and 6 look interesting. Take $N=4$ and subtract $3$ from the expected number of vertices to get your probability.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a different approach to the problem. Consider a random triangle illustrated below. Regions are labelled near ($N_i$) and far ($F_i$) from point $i$. $T$ is the triangle. [image: random triange illustrating random regions in the unit square]

If the 4th point falls in regions $F_1$, $F_2$, or $F_3$ a convex quadrilateral will result. The probability that 4 points produce a convex shape is equivalent to the probability that the 4th point will be in one of those regions. That is, $p=E[F_1+F_2+F_3]$ where $F_i$ is the random variable expressing the area of that region.

To simplify the calculations, consider the shaded region labelled $A_1$ and the counterparts $A_2$ and $A_3$.
$$F_1+N_2+N_3=A_1$$
$$N_1+F_2+F_3+T=1-A_1$$
Combining these one finds,
$$F_1+F_2+F_3 = 2 - 2T - A_1 - A_2 - A_3$$
and therefore,
$$p=E[F_1+F_2+F_3]=2 - 2E[T] - 3E[A]$$
Fortunately [others](https://www.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:644463/FULLTEXT01.pdf) have worked out $E[T]={11\over144}$

To work out $E[A]$, I considered separately the case where the unit square is bisected across opposite sides (as is the case for $A_1$). You can show that this occurs with probability ${2\over3}$, given two uniform random points. The smallest of the two areas $A_\min$ follows the distribution $$f(a_\min)=4a_\min$$ 
for $0<a_\min<{1\over2}$. Given the two points $(2,3)$ point $1$ point will fall in the smaller of the two areas with probability $a_\min$, in which case $A_1=1-a_\min$.
$$
E[A_{opp}]=16\int_0^{1\over2}a_\min^2(1-a_\min)\,da_\min = {5\over12}
$$

For the case where the unit square is cut across a corner (as is the case for $A_2$), $A_\min={1\over2}X_0Y_0$ where $X_0$ and $Y_0$ are independent random variables with the identical distribution, $f(x)=2x$ for $0<x<1$. This gives the distribution for $A_\min$, 
$$f(a_\min)=-16 a_\min \log 2a_\min$$ 
for $0<a_\min<{1\over2}$.
$$
E[A_{corner}]=-32\int_0^{1\over2}a_\min^2(1-a_\min)\log 2a_\min\,da_\min = {23\over72}
$$
And so, overall
$$E[A] = P(A_{opp})E[A_{opp}]+P(A_{corner})E[A_{corner}]={2\over3}{5\over12}+{1\over3}{23\over72} = {83\over216}$$
Finally,
$$
p = 2 - 2{11\over144} - 3{83\over216}={25\over36}=\left({5\over6}\right)^2=0.69\bar{4}
$$
which is close to your simulation result. A very simple form!

Answer (score 2):

$P_{convex}=\int_0^1 da  a_{123}p(a_{123})$
where $a_{123}=\frac{1}{2}\left|(\mathbf{x}_{12} \times \mathbf{x}_{13})\right|$
this is the probability that the 4th point falls within the triangle formed by the first three. Normalization included due to unit square, and 
$$p(a)=\frac{1}{2} \int_0^1 dx_1 \int_0^1 dx_2 \int_0^1 dx_3 \int_0^1 dy_1 \int_0^1 dy_2 \int_0^1 dy_3 \delta \left( a - \sqrt{\left( (x_2 - x_1)^2 (y_3 - y_1)^2 + (y_2 - y_1)^2 (x_3 - x_1)^2  \right) } \right)$$

an integral which might be difficult to evaluate in closed form, where $\delta(x)$ is the Dirac delta function.

The $p(a)$ probability density function for the area of the triangle formed by three uniformly random points in the unit square seems to fit quite well to the beta distribution with $\alpha = 1.18$ and $\beta = 5.1$ and an upper bound of $\frac{1}{2}$

The percentage of fourth points that fall inside the triangle formed by first three is then the expectation of the area $E\left[a\right]=\frac{\alpha / 2}{\alpha+\beta}$ or ~10%, corresponding to concave fraction of 90%. Seems off ...

[image]

Also looked at the distribution of the maximum area of the 4 triangles formed by a set of 4 points each picked from $(U[0,1],U[0,1])
Mean moves from 9% to 15%

[image]

Comment: Can you evaluate the integral for me?

Comment: not in closed form, no

Comment: I appreciate your effort. I think what you have is an approximation to Sylvester's 4 point problem which has a probability of $\frac{11}{144}$. Then considering that I don't mind which point is not part of the convex hull, we multiply by 4 for the 4 possible points on the inside. Unfortunately, this is not the answer to the question as there are additional spaces outside the triangle formed by the first 3 points that would also give a convex hull with 3 points. A good effort and the current front runner for the bounty as we now know that $\frac{11}{36}$ is a lower bound.

Comment: Perhaps find the expected are of the largest triangle formed from randomly placing 4 points?

Comment: appended amax distribution to answer

Comment: Looks good. I think if you multiply that by 4 then you get Sylvester's 4 point problem solution discussed above. Thanks for your help.