# Number of vertices of a random convex polygon

Tags: probability, combinatorics, puzzle, geometric-probability, plane-geometry

Take $n>2$ random points, chosen independently with uniform probability on $[0,1]\times[0,1]$. What is the probability $P(n,k)$ that the convex hull of these points is a polygon with exactly $2<k\leq n$ vertices?

It seems that $P(3,3)=1$, since after choosing two points, the probability that the third point will be on the line between them is $0$.

For $P(4,4)$, assume 3 points have already been chosen, then their convex hull is a triangle which is the intersection of 3 half spaces. The fourth point will create a quadrilateral if and only if it lies in the intersection of exactly two of the above half spaces. But how can we calculate this area? And what if $n>4$? Then things get really tricky!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a very broad question. $P(n,n)$ and $P(n,3)$ are known, and this allows $P(5,4)$ to be deduced. I'm not aware that any other values are known.

For $k=n$, the answer is given in the dissertation [Probability that $n$ random points are in convex position](http://www.diss.fu-berlin.de/docs/servlets/MCRFileNodeServlet/FUDOCS_derivate_000000000261/1994_01.pdf) (Pavel Valtr, 1994):

$$
P(n,n)=\left(\frac{\binom{2n-2}{n-1}}{n!}\right)^2\;.
$$

For $k=3$, the event that the convex hull consists of three points is the union of the disjoint events that one of the $\binom n3$ triangles formed by $3$ of the $n$ points contains the remaining $n-3$ points. The probability for each of these events is the $(n-3)$-rd power of the probability that a point lies in the triangle formed by three points, which is the $(n-3)$-rd moment of the area of the triangle. These moments are given at [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SquareTrianglePicking.html), and multiplying them by $\binom n3$ yields

$$
P(n,3)=2^{5-n}\frac{(n-1)H_{n-2}+1}{n(n-1)^2}\;,
$$

where $H_n$ is the $n$-th harmonic number.

From $P(5,3)+P(5,4)+P(5,5)=1$ we can also deduce $P(5,4)=\frac59$.

Here are the values for $n\le5$:

\begin{array}{c|cc}
n\setminus k&3&4&5\\\hline
3&1\\
4&\frac{11}{36}&\frac{25}{36}\\
5&\frac5{48}&\frac59&\frac{49}{144}\\
\end{array}

You can read more about them at [Expected size of subset forming convex polygon.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/280648) and at [How is the number of points in the convex hull of five random points distributed?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/282147), where the distribution $P(5,k)$ is derived in a different way.

Comment: This is a really nice answer; it always amazes me what references people have handy. I'm surprised it hasn't gotten much positive reception, but even more surprised those $P(n, k)$ values are all rational. That seems so unlikely!

Comment: This reference also! The topic is "Random Convex Hulls" - https://arxiv.org/abs/1111.5340